# How do I evaluate this sum :$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n!)}{\cos(n!)}$ if it's not open problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I proposed [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1335592/248451) question on MSE but some comments affirmed that is  unsolved problem and no answer. I would like to see what MO say about it.

How do I evaluate this sum :$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n!)}{\cos(n!)}$$

Note : I used many criterions of convergence to test whether it converges but i didn't succeed.

Thank you for any help .

Comment: I'd be surprised if it did converge!

Comment: Presumably the set of values $\{ n! \bmod 2\pi\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in the interval $[0,2\pi]$, in which case $\tan(n!)$ will be arbitrarily large, infinitely often. So your series is highly unlikely to be absolutely convergent. (Whether one can prove this or not, I don't know.) Conditional convergence also seems unlikely. But it might be interesting to try to prove $\sum_{n\le X}\tan(n!)=o(X)$, or even $O(X^\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon<1$. (I haven't thought about it, maybe this is easy, maybe not.)

Comment: Actually, it's not clear that there's even a polynomial bound, i.e., $\sum_{n\le X}\tan(n!)=O(X^K)$ for some $K>0$. Rigorously, probably the best one can do is use transcendence estimates for $\pi$ to bound $n!$ away from multiples of $\pi/2$ where $\tan$ blows up, which is going to yield an effective, but horrible, upper bound in terms of $X$.

Comment: On the other hand, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \tan(\pi n! /e)$ will converge.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Very tricky. But it's not absolutely convergent, right, because $\tan(\pi n!/e) = (-1)^{n+1}/(n+1) + O(1/n^2) \pmod{\mathbb Z}$?

Comment: You mean $n!/e = (-1)^{n+1}/(n+1) + O(1/n^2) (\mod \mathbb Z)$, so $\tan(\pi n!/e) = (-1)^{n+1} \pi/(n+1) + O(1/n^2)$.  Yes, the sum converges conditionally.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, in the answer no analytical proof to show that the sum is diverge only visualization

Comment: If you want one that converges absolutely, try $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \tan(\pi (2n)! (e + 1/e)/2)$

Comment: @Zeraouliarafik I have no analytical proof for $\sum_n \tan(n!)$ diverging either.  It seems to me very unlikely that Diophantine-approximation bounds for $\pi$ could be anywhere near good enough to prove this.

Comment: May be add "x" and change $\sin(n!)$ to $\sin(n!x)$ ? In this form it is a so called lacunar Fourier series, there are a lot of results on convergence for them. May be some result will help?

Comment: @sergi, do you meant it return to tan(n!x) ?

Comment: @JoeSilverman Do you know how to prove that $\{ n! \bmod 2\pi\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $[0,2\pi]$? Sorry to be this late, but I have this exact question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I computed $f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n \tan(k!)$ for different $n$,
and got the following plot. It does not seem to have a limit.

[image: Sums for different n]

Mathematica code:

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 600},
 lst = Table[Tan[n!], {n, 0, 200}];
 ListPlot[N[Accumulate[lst], 200], PlotRange -> All]
 ]
```

Comment: i have the same plot with wolfram alpha but what about analytical proof ?

Comment: It's probably more interesting to look at the values of something like $\sup_{n\le N} \frac{\log|f(n)|}{\log n}$ and see if it looks as if there might be a polynomial bound for $|f(n)|$.

Comment: Joe Silverman gives a good argument. I guess to actually prove that $n!$ mod $2\pi \mathbb{Z}$ is dense is quite nontrivial, and perhaps even an open problem.

Comment: @JoeSilverman: Ah, yes, it looks like $\log|f(n)|/\log(n) \leq 1.64$ for $n \leq 600$, and $g(N)=\sup_{n\leq N} \frac{\log|f(n)|}{\log(n)}$ is very close to being constant.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson, thank you for your answer, did you meant that the sum diverge and have no luck to be converge ?

Comment: and what about for large n, is it the same ?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson , I don't know why the downvote for my question ?

Comment: That was not intended; browsing on the phone apparently has some unexpected consequences.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson I upvoted to compensate for that.